# Refactor ruby code to split array into two small arrays

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

```
  @open  = Array.new
  @close = Array.new
  @posts.each do |post|
     if !post.status.nil? and post.status == 'Open'
        @open.push(post)
     else
        @close.push(post)
     end
  end
```

Can i write it in less verbose way ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sounds like a job for [`partition`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-partition):

> **partition { |obj| block } → [ true_array, false_array ]**
>   **partition → an_enumerator**
>
> Returns two arrays, the first containing the elements of *enum* for which the block evaluates to true, the second containing the rest.

This should do the job:

```
@open, @closed = @posts.partition { |p| p.status == 'Open' }
```

Comment: Nice answer. How long you are in Ruby/Rails ? :-)

Comment: Humm.. I am closely 2 years in Ruby. Still crawling.. :-(

Answer (score 1):

Another idea:

```
@open = @post.select{ |post| post.status == 'Open'}
@close = @post.reject{ |post| post.status == 'Open'}
```

Comment: You could replace your second line with `@close = @post - @open`.

Answer (score 0):

You dont have to check nil explicity. Something like this will do.

```
@posts.each { |post| post.status == 'Open' ? @open.push post : @close.push }
```

Comment: @HunterMcMillen you got a point in there. You may need the nil check depending on your data.

Answer (score 0):

Just to help you write code that's more Ruby-like, here's how I'd write your original code:

```
open_ary  = []
close_ary = []
@posts.each do |post|
  if post.status && post.status == 'Open'
    open_ary << post
  else
    close_ary << post
  end
end
```

It could be written more concisely, and would remove a couple lines, but it'd lose readability, which is always something to consider. That said, @muistooshort's answer is really the best way to do it because it relies on the `partition` method which was created for this sort of use-case.